# Reset the validation message in LWC Flow Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, flow-screen-component

I created LWC component that is going to be used in Flow.
I'm using validate method() to handle custom validation logic when the user clicks the standard 'Next' button.
The message is shown under my component as expected, but then at some point, I want to clear this message. As far as I understand, I should do it using FlowAttributeChangeEvent, so here is my code:

```js
import { FlowAttributeChangeEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class SomeRandomComponent extends LightningElement {
    someRequiredValue = '';

    @api
    validate() {
        //this is my validation, it works as expected, validation message id displayed
        if (!this.someRequiredValue) {
            return {
                isValid: false,
                errorMessage: 'someRequiredValue should not be empty'
            };
        }
    }

    handleSomeEvent() {
        // some value is assigned to someRequiredValue
        this.someRequiredValue = 'test';
        //and now I want to reset validation messages
        const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('someRequiredValue ', this.someRequiredValue);
        this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent);
    }
}
```

My HTML and metadata file (I don't think that they are relevant here)

```html
<template>
    <lightning-button variant="base" label="Click Me" onclick={handleSomeEvent}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? When FlowAttributeChangeEvent is emitted, I would expect my validation error message to disappear. Maybe there is some other way of removing this message?

Comment: Hi , In the FlowAttributeChangeEvent constructor, the first parameter should be the name of the attribute that you want to update in the Flow.
And to clear the validation message, you need to update the attribute that you used to store the error message in the first place. In your example, you returned an object with the errorMessage property from the validate() method, but you did not store it anywhere.